# "E426: tag not found error" when generating tags

Tags: vim, macvim, exuberant-ctags

I've got a macvim snapshot 64 downloaded from [here](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases) and exuberant ctags installed via `homebrew`:

```
which ctags
/usr/local/bin/ctags
```

my `tags` variable in vim looks like this:

```
:echo &tags
/Users/macovsky/code/faces/tmp/tags,./tags,tags,/Users/macovsky/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/tags,/Users/macovsky/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/tags,/Users/macovsky/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/tags,/Users/macovsky/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/tags,/Users/macovsky/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/tags,/Users/macovsky/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/tags,/Users/macovsky/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tags,/Users/macovsky/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/tags,/Users/macovsky/code/faces/tags
```

and I generated the tags file with `rails-vim`'s `:Rtags` command:

```
file tmp/tags 
tmp/tags: Exuberant Ctags tag file text
```

the problem is that whether I use `C-]` or `:tag` it all fails with a `E426 tag not found` error.

The tag is definitely there:

```
cat tmp/tags | grep post_image
post_image  /Users/macovsky/code/faces/app/helpers/posts_helper.rb  /^  def post_image(post, style)$/;" f   class:PostsHelper
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: This happens to me to, did you ever get a solution?

Comment: @macovsky I am guessing its the way you set up the tags file. Did you try using ctags -R ? This recursively searches for all the directories for files and gets tags from them

Comment: He said the tag is definitely there. Is it possible that the tags are being generated with a relative path to a directory that is throwing vim off?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you added a semicolon to your tag paths in .vimrc:

```
set tags=./tags;,./gems.tags;
```

There is [an explanation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11199/what-does-a-semicolon-mean-in-the-tags-option).

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you define the tags to be in tmp/tags, however your tags variable only holds a link to a tags file in the current directory.

Try either putting your tags file in the current directory or add ./tmp/tags to your vim tags variable.
(I would prefer the first option)

\Paul

Comment: If the tag file is not found vim gives an additional error code: `E433: No tags file`.